# How to get unique and consistent device id on Android device

Tags: android, security, encryption

I need to generate a device ID that complies the following criteria:

It is universally unique.
It is consistent (as much as possible), i.e. it stays the same for the same device.
It requires minimal permissions.
It is legal to be transferred and stored.
The solution, for example, could be a hardware ID which is accessible with no special permissions which is then hashed and sent over the wire, I just don't know if there is any.

---

*P.S. Devices must not be rooted, and I don't want to store anything in any sort of keychains or anywhere else. Just generate on the fly, and remain the same, independently from the app it's being generated on. And resetting it during factory reset or other rare occasions is fine.*

Comment: imei number should be unique with respect to device

Comment: Use instance id though : https://developers.google.com/instance-id/

Comment: One more option :  `String imsi = android.os.SystemProperties.get(android.telephony.TelephonyProperties.PROPERTY_IMSI);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 private String getIMEINumber() {
    TelephonyManager mngr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return mngr.getDeviceId();

}
```

And in Manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

IMEI is unique for every device

OR you can get MAC address:

```
WifiManager wifiManager (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
String macid = wInfo.getMacAddress();
```

Don't forget to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: but it can be multiple for a single device

Comment: by default it takes the first one if multiple are available and others are not accessible